# cron job to run google-musicmanager and have its indicator showing up in the menu bar

Tags: indicator, cron, google-musicmanager

For some reasons, I need to periodically run a script with cron in order to start Google Music Manager (and to perform some music folders/files and config management stuff, which poses no problem).

Everything is working well, except one thing:  the Google Music Manager indicator is not showing up in the menu bar when started by cron (but the app is really running in the background and the uploading of songs work, etc.).  However, if I run the script from the terminal, the indicator does show up.

I'm pretty sure that this problem has something to do with some environment variable (I have already put "export DISPLAY=:0.0" in the script), but I can't pinpoint which one...  Here's the script I'm running:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
export DISPLAY=:0.0
killall MusicManager
#some music folders/files and config management stuff
google-musicmanager
exit
```

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks.